# Website wider than 100%

Tags: css, layout, resize, responsive-design, width

If you take a look at [this](http://s23.postimg.org/noiku8xaj/Problem1.png) picture you'll see that there is a small gap beside my navigation bar, which is set to 100% width and is supposed to cover the whole screen. It might be hard to see the gap but the scrollbar, which is not intended, is visible.  Using `overflow-x: hidden;` wasn't a viable solution because of the `scrollto` functions I'm using it scrolls my page to the right automatically. Minimizing the window makes the gap even bigger as shown in [this](http://s16.postimg.org/pc6c9w5d1/Problem2.png) image. You can also see me selecting the body element which does not cover the gap.

Part of my code:

```
body {
    40px 0 20px 0
}
#navigation {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height: 40px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    width: 100%;
    top: 90px;
}
#Main {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: 175px;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    left: -130px;
}
#sidebar .content {
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
.Post {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

Now I tried to move my sidebar closer to the left, and that actually removed the initial gap. The gap that appears when you resize is still there, and if you remove the whole sidebar it makes it smaller. So I guess there is something else that is pushing the page. I searched and found some questions with similar problem where they suggested you to remove the float and left/right properties but they didn't work.

So my question is simple: How do I remove the gap(s) but still keep the layout? Or what can be the cause of the problem?

**EDIT:** I just tried to remove the sidebar AND the posts and it seemed to solve it. The problem is how can I keep them? The gap is probably caused by either #sidebar or .Post, or #Main which is wrapped around them both. I don't think there's anything wrong with the body tag as removing the #main contents solved it.

Comment: First off, what is that inside your `body`-tag? Next, when setting things to 100%, also set the body and the html to 100% width.

Comment: Consider using the image upload function of the editor, that way your pictures won't disappear so future visitors can still see them.

Comment: The body tag would be everything inside <body> </body>. The blue selection in picture 2 is everything inside the body. I tried setting html and body to 100% width but that didn't change anything. It says that the Html document only covers 1343px (which is 100% on my screen) but as shown in picture 2 the gap is comming from nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS has issues, I'm assuming you want:

```
body{
  margin:40px 0 20px;
}
```

`body` should automatically be 100%, so my code above should work, but remember that `%` is based on the containing block, so `#navigation` would not be able to be inside any other elements, for `100%` to work.

Note that other elements may automatically stretch your `body`, if they are lager than your screen. Depending on what you are doing you may want to use `px` or `em`, or use JavaScript to determine your screen size. Save the following on a page called `widthfix.js`:

```
var win = window, doc = document, bod = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function matchScreenWidth(element){
  var w = win.innerWidth || bod.clientWidth || doc.documentElement.clientWidth;
  element.style.width = w+'px';
}
```

Now, at the bottom of your `body`:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='widthfix.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    matchScreenWidth(E('navigation'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That line of code came with the theme. But I tried that, did not change anything. However, I just tried to remove the sidebar AND my posts, the gap disappeared. So removing everything but the navigation and keep the empty Main, which is wrapped around Sidebar and .Post, solved it. Problem is how can I keep them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to fix this. Use width:100% on your #main and give it a max-width:1000px; and that will mean that it will be1000px where it can, or fit itself when the window is too small.

It might be easier if you we're able to put e structure itself into a us fiddle, or paste the live link, so we can play around with the CSS and see what needs fixing.